# Find lat/long on a straight line between two other coordinates

Tags: geometry

I'm working on a mobile app and have two coordinates (`LatLngA` and `LatLngB`) which are on a straight distance of 100 meters from each other.

I also have the initial bearing from `LatLngA` to `LatLngB`.

I need to find out `LatLngC` in between these two coordinates at a given distance `X`.

I see that the first answer of this question might help: [How to find a point between two points with given distance?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045174/how-to-find-a-point-between-two-points-with-given-distance). But I'm not sure how to find unit vectors in x and y direction.

As you might have figured, I'm not a mathematician, so I'm looking for a simplified answer that could be used in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If point $A$ and $B$ have coordinates $A=(x_A,y_A)$, $B=(x_B,y_B)$, and 
$d=\sqrt{(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2}$, then the coordinates of $C$ are 
$$C=\left(x_A+(x_B-x_A){x\over d},\ y_A+(y_B-y_A){x\over d}\right).$$