# Another point distance question.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Please excuse my complete ignorance on what should really be something I can work out myself but hoping someone would be kind enough to help.

I am trying to solve the problem where I wish to calculate a point along a line n distance from point p1.

I have looked at the questions [How do I find a point a given distance from another point along a line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409689/how-do-i-find-a-point-a-given-distance-from-another-point-along-a-line/409721) and [How to find a point between two points with given distance?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045174/how-to-find-a-point-between-two-points-with-given-distance) and have tried to apply them to a trivial case for which I know the answer but seem to be stuck.

I have used a trivial example to test where I have point 1 which is 1,1 and point 2 which is 5,1 and I want to calculate 1 step from point 1 which I expect would give me the result 2,1.

When I attempted to calculate these values based on the above formulas I did the following:

y3 = 1 + 1/4 * (1-1)

x3 = 1 + 1/4 * (5-1)

Which gave me the result
2,1.25

Clearly I have messed up somewhere but I am not sure where, can anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Comment: you get $x_3=1+\frac14(5-1)=1+\frac44=2$ and $y_3=1+\frac14(1-1)=1+0=1$

Comment: How is your question related to [tag:trigonometry]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am not sure where this question is supposed to be and I am happy to change it. I apologise if I have put it in the wrong category

Comment: It seems to me that [tag:analytic-geometry] is a much better choice.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for that and I really do appreciate everyones super quick response, just do try to keep in mind that things that seem trivial for you guys are far from for us mere mortals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clearly I have messed up somewhere but I am not sure where

It appears that you computed $1-1=1$ instead of $1-1=0$ when applying the formula for $y_3$,

so you got $1.25$ instead of $1$.

Comment: Of course. I am a complete idiot. I didnt compute 1-1 = 1. I Simply ignored BODMAS. So basically its 1 + (1/4 * 0) = 1? Instead I added 1 + 0.25 first.... Thank you!!!!

Comment: Yes, it's $1+\frac14(0)=1$

Comment: Thank you again, much appreciated! and sorry for wasting your time